# source code for all of my files has changed

Tags: divshot

I have created a total of 9 sample pages for my project.  I tagged three of them as templates to speed the design process.  I successfully exported all nine files but upon returning to my account discovered that all nine files had some how revered to the same source code.

In other words, instead of 9 distinctly different pages I have 9 copies of the same page.  How could this happen and how can I fix this?  I need to continue my work but with no way to correct this problem or upload my correct files form my previous export I feel as if I need to either start over or do all of my editing in an HTML editor manually going forward.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do backup next time. I don't think you would be able to retrieve your "OLD files" if you didn't back them up and without UPLOADING your previous files.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I am not able to find a "Backup" option in the Divshot interface.  I exported my code as a fail safe.

Answer (score 0):

Please get in touch with support if you lost any data and we'll work with you to get it restored right away. Bugs like these are always high priority and we want to make sure your data is never lost.

In the new version of Divshot saving is now manual and with version history you now have the option to revert back to a previous version of a file at any time. All data is backed up on Amazon S3 with versioning.

After upgrading let me know if you continue to experience issues with cloning pages or using templates. We'll be happy to help!